# Combinations in Repeated Data Set

Tags: combinatorics

Six cards chosen at a time from double-deck playing cards can have 1,517,381,580 unique combinations --> C(52*2,6).  Each deck has 13 kinds, and 4 suits.  But in this problem all 4 suits are treated the same, and therefore; this double-deck card set has repeated data and is effectively consisting of eight 1s, eight 2s, eight 3s … eight Js, eight Qs, and 8 Ks, and the data set used to generate the 6-card combinations was arranged in order as follows:

- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, T, J, Q, K
- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, T, J, Q, K
- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, T, J, Q, K
- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, T, J, Q, K
- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, T, J, Q, K
- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, T, J, Q, K
- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, T, J, Q, K
- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, T, J, Q, K

During the review of my computer generated data set, I noticed that the 1,517,381,580 unique combinations can be "compressed" into 5 groups of repeatable combinations due to the presence of repeated data in the 2-deck set:

6-card combinations * repetition factors (2-deck set):

- (a) 18,564 * 28
- (b) 606,333 * 84
- (c) 2,294,929 * 210
- (d) 1,687,049 * 462
- (e) 218,218 * 924
- (f) 1716 * 1716

(FYI, 4-deck set has identical combinations, but with much bigger repetition factors)

Example: There are 18,564 combinations in group (a), and each of these combinations is repeated 28 times, which generates a total combination of --> 18,564*28 = 519,792

Check Sum:  18,564*28 + 606,333*84 + 2,294,929*210 + 1,687,049*462 + 218,218*924 + 1716*1716 = 1,517,381,580.

Question for everyone:  What are the mathematical equations or functions that represent the repetition factors in groups (a) through (f)?

Comment: You have not specified what your six groups are.

Comment: I was referring to the six groups listed in the question, and would like to know mathematical representations of these factors without first knowing or determining the actual number of combinations associate with these factors.  I believe that the six repetition factors corresponding to the six patterns (a) to (f) cited in the question can be determined by solving simultaneous equations when the combinations and other combinations in sub-groups (such as no-rank, pairs, kinds/pairs etc…) are defined or pre-determined.